# Crash after restart with new monitor settings

Tags: 14.04, boot, rotate-monitor

14.04, Dell Vostro 3546

Hi

I went to Settings - Displays and set Rotation to Counterclockwise. That worked great, but after rebooting my system and logging in, nothing loaded. I got the normal mouse cursor on a black background, then the cursor rotated to Counterclockwise, but nothing else happened (for however long i waited.) There was just the rotated cursor on a black background. No launcher, no wallpaper, no keyboard shortcuts working, no panel. Forcing shutdown with the hardware button and booting into recovery let me boot without Counterclockwise (or the resulting bug) kicking in, but in that recovery mode it's not possible to disable Counterclockwise again, because that setting is not adjustable in recovery mode. So when I then reboot normally again, the same lonely, rotated cursor appears again.

Eventually I just overwrote my whole Ubuntu partition with a Clonezilla image from a few days back. Now, if I want to continue using Counterclockwise view (which I do,) I have to switch it back to Normal every time I want to power down or reboot, and then switch it back to Counterclockwise again upon boot. I also have to keep regular Timeshift/Clonezilla backups in case my computer crashes or inadvertently powers down while in Counterclockwise mode. This is actually what I am doing at the moment, but it's hardly handy for a native function in the standard build.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked syslog?

Comment: Like when it's crashed. Or is it unresponsive?

Comment: How can I check anything when there is no Unity Launcher, no keyboard shortcuts working, no panel, etc?

Comment: You can try using ctrl-alt-f1 and logging in there. Them do `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Alright , I managed to do that . Here's the output. Does it offer any clues ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzNxi0d0XwrRMUVIMDZicEQyWEk/view?usp=docslist_api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. I have written it in an extremely beginner-friendly fashion. This is the way I personally prefer instructions to be written.

First, boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

1. I Searched the launcher (super+A) for "gedit" and opened "Text Editor".
2. Typed the following into the blank document

`#!/bin/bash
xrandr -o normal &
sleep 1s
xrandr -o left`

3. Saved the file to the desktop and named it Screen.sh

(I'm pretty sure it can be saved anywhere and named anything.)

4. Went to where I saved the file, right clicked on the file, and selected "Properties". Clicked the "Permissions" tab, and ticked the box next to "Allow executing as a program." Then I closed that window.
5. Searched the launcher (Super+A) for "startup" and launched "Startup Applications".
6. Clicked "Add." Typed something (anything) in the "Name" box.
7. Typed the following into the "Command" field: `/home/fiksdal/Desktop/Screen.sh

Replace "fiksdal" with your own login name or replace the whole path if you saved it somewhere else.

7. Restarted my computer.

The computer took a few seconds to adjust itself upon reboot, but it turned out just fine, and it put itself into Counterclockwise view without freezing or screwing up.

Hope this is helpful to someone.